# How to determine in CefSharp that the response from the server is 404?

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

I am using WPF control for CefSharp. I need to know when the request I made receives a response with http status code 404.

I've noticed that CefSharp has LoadError event, but that only fires when the domain cannot be resolved altogether (i.e. if I go to www.sdfhjkhajsdf.com). It doesn't work for when the domain exists, but the page your requesting doesn't.

Comment: Implement `IRequestHandler`, use `IRequestHandler.OnResourceResponse`, you can check the `response.StatusCode`. Search the project source if you require more examples.

Comment: @amaitland that worked thank you! but I have a different problem now. The ResourceResponse event is only fired once for me when I open the page with initial url. Any subsequent calls to Load(url) are not firing that event. What could be the cause for that?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your code. If you post your `IRequestHandler` implementation as a `Gist` or something similar I can have a look. http://gist.github.com/

Comment: tbh it's very simple. I just took the one from the sources and removed some bits that were put there as examples. here you go: https://gist.github.com/ncksol/0226c325bbcfdeda93f45a1ff1723b8d

Comment: Adding a `breakpoint` to the `CefSharp.Example.RequestHandler` class and it fires as expected. Can you reproduce your problem using the example (Download and compile source)? What version are you using?

Comment: That's the worst thing - the example runs just fine for me. I get the event to fire every time. But in my project for some reason it doesn't. I am using the same Load method of the webcontrol and pass the url. I am on 47.0.3. Here is the codebehind for the control that contains the CefSharp browser control, maybe there is something in how I initialise it? - https://gist.github.com/ncksol/76fcb3218fc695270c2a064004f2c3b8

Comment: Can you use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to be able to reproduce this in the minimal example. Would you mind take a look at the way I am setting up the webbrowser in the link above? I wonder if the problem is somewhere there.

Comment: Is there a reason you assign `RequestHandler` twice? Looks like you have two different implementations.

Comment: Wow this is really embarrassing. Looks like RequestHandler has been already created some time ago, but I just didn't notice it. Thanks for your help! Can you please put you original comment as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question. CefSharp has had lots of great updates, so I hope this helps others searching like me. Don't hate me because my snippets are in VB.NET. ;)

This is what I'm doing to log anything that is not 200 response. For my application, I open a new form of the requested page, so I limit my focus to the initial page request by looking at the `ReferrerUrl` property. Obviously, you could drop that part to be alerted to all requests.

When you initially implement your `ChromiumWebBrowser` you need to set a `RequestHandler` to your implementation.

```
Me.chromeBrowser = New CefSharp.WinForms.ChromiumWebBrowser(uri)
Me.chromeBrowser.RequestHandler = New CefBasicRequestHandler()
Me.Controls.Add(Me.chromeBrowser)
```

CefSharp released a default implementation that you can use and just override `OnResourceResponse`.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Imports CefSharp

Public Class CefBasicRequestHandler
  Inherits CefSharp.Handler.DefaultRequestHandler

  Private Shared ReadOnly Logger As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)

  Public Overrides Function OnResourceResponse(browserControl As IWebBrowser, browser As IBrowser, frame As IFrame, request As IRequest, response As IResponse) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.ReferrerUrl) Then ' this is the first request of the page
        Dim method As String = "OnResourceResponse()."
        Dim requestOverview As String = $"[{response.StatusCode}] [{request.Url}]"
        Logger.Info($"{method} {requestOverview}")

        If response.StatusCode <> 200 Then
            Logger.Warn($"{method} {requestOverview}")
        End If
    End If

    Return MyBase.OnResourceResponse(browserControl, browser, frame, request, response)
  End Function
End Class
```